# Unmanaged deployment of exploded jar file in wildfly 10 domain mode

Tags: deployment, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-10

I am trying to deploy exploded jar file which has ejb's through unmanaged deployment in domain mode from admin console of Wildfly 10.1.0.

But when I deploy the same I get ClassNotFoundException for all ejb'same
The same setup work  in standalone mode.
Is there any extra settings for the same??

```
MyJar.jar
--->classes
--->META-INF
     ---->MANIFEST.MF (with all dependent modules)
```

Created **deploy** folder inside wildfly-home and this **deploy** folder has **MyJar.jar** exploded folder.
This class com.action.ejb.session.ManagerBean is in MyJar.jar exploded folder.

```
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.action.ejb.session.ManagerBean from [Module "deployment.MyJar.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
[Server:server-one]     at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.getEjbClass(BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.java:239)
[Server:server-one]     at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.deploy(BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.java:89)
[Server:server-one]     at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
```

Comment: Why do you need an exploded jar?

Comment: @SteveC that is for development mode. For hot deployment i have kept as exploded folder

Comment: I think that "hot deploying" in domain mode would be somewhat unusual. Even then I never bother with exploded deployments during development either.

Comment: Upgrade to WildFly 11beta 1 as this is supported with managed deployments : https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/Application+deployment